# Import data from old website into new drupal website having diffrent schema

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to import data from an old website into a new Drupal-based website. Both do have a completely different database schema. Can anybody help how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check out on the Migrate module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate

It can import from any kind of DB organization, if you define import rules, but there are also some sub-modules of this module, specialized for i.e. importing from WordPress or another Drupal site, Typo site and similar.